# copying a dataframe of file paths into a new folder in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing a bunch of file paths. I am trying to copy the files with these paths into a new folder. My attempt is `file.copy(data1,"E:\\Contracts\\MainContracts")`, where data1 is my dataframe and "E:\Contracts\MainContracts" is the path to the destination folder.
'from' path too long
When I run this I get "'from' path too long". Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example that will first write 3 files to your desktop in a folder called 'demo' and then copy all the files into another director on your desktop 'demo-copy'. We need to make sure we have either the full path names of the files to move or set the working directory to the folder they are in if not. Also `file.copy` takes a character vector in the 'from' argument so we need to pass column of file paths from the dataframe by indexing with the `$`.

See if this example gives you an idea of the workflow:

```
library(purrr)
#create example data
data_to_save <- list(mtcars, iris, ToothGrowth)
filenames <- paste0('~/Desktop/demo/', c('mtcars', 'iris', 'ToothGrowth'), '.csv')
dir.create('~/Desktop/demo')
purrr::walk2(data_to_save, filenames, ~write.csv(.x, .y))

#copy all files to new folder
df_of_filenames <- data.frame(filename = list.files('~/Desktop/demo', pattern = '.csv', full.names = T))
dir.create('~/Desktop/demo-copy')
file.copy(df_of_filenames$filename, '~/Desktop/demo-copy/')
```